# Stuck at "creating transaction"

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I'm trying to send funds but when I press "send", a new window titled "Creating transaction" pops up with a nonstop running circle hanging there forever....

I've tried twice and it's the same. The funds are not sent and I have to force close it.

Latest GUI 0.11.1.0 Helium Hydra linux 64bit.

Comment: Are you using your own (local) node or a remote node?

Comment: How long did you wait? If you're using a remote node under high load, it could take a while to fetch random outputs. in that case, wait longer, try a different remote node, or even better, run your own local node. You could also check the wallet log (monero-wallet-gui.log) for more info.

Comment: OK. Was using a remote node. Maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An update to the current version **0.13.0.4 Beryllium Bullet** of the Monero GUI wallet for Linux should solve your issue.